# LED sequence control by button

Tags: led

I want to make sequential LED by using arduino that controlled by button. 
If I press + button, LED will increase from L1 to (L1 and L2 is HIGH), then I press button again, L1, L2, and L3 will be HIGH. If I press again, all the LED (L1, L2, L3, L4) will be high. 
Same case if I press “ – “ button, LED will be lower from the previous state. Which mean that if L1, L2, and L3 is HIGH. There will be L1 and L2 only HIGH if I press ‘ – ‘ button. I dont how to do it. This is code for increase but I dont know how to make it reverse flow.

```
const int buttonPin = 2; // the pin number of the pushbutton input pin  
int ledPins[] = {3, 4, 5,};  
 // variables will change:  
 int buttonState = 0; // variable for reading the pushbutton status  
 int buttonPressCount = 0;  
 int numberOfLED = 3;  
 void setup() {  
  // initialize the LED pin as an output:  
  for (int i = 0; i < numberOfLED; i++) {  
   pinMode(ledPins[i], OUTPUT);  
  }  
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);  
 }  
 void loop() {  
  // read the state of the pushbutton value:  
  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);  
  // check if the pushbutton is pressed.  
  // if it is, the buttonState is HIGH:  
  if (buttonState == HIGH) {  
   for (int i = 0; i < numberOfLED; i++) {  
    if (buttonPressCount % numberOfLED == i) {  
     // turn LED on:  
     digitalWrite(ledPins[i], HIGH);  
    } else {  
     // turn LED off:  
     digitalWrite(ledPins[i], LOW);  
    }  
   }  
   buttonPressCount++;  
   delay(400);  
  }  
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My original answer was probably over-kill....Just keep track of how many leds are lit:

```c
int ledPins[] = {3, 4, 5,};
const int num_leds = sizeof(ledPins) / sizeof(ledPins[0]);  // 3 in this example
byte num_leds_lit = 0

void set_leds() {
    for (int i = 0; i < num_leds; i++) {
        digitalWrite(ledPins[i], i < num_leds_lit ? HIGH : LOW);
    }
}
```

Then, on button press, increase the count:

```c
if (num_leds_lit < num_leds) {
    num_leds_lit += 1;
    set_leds();
}
```

Then to turn the leds off with the other button press:

```c
if (num_leds_lit > 0) {
    num_leds_lit -= 1;
    set_leds();
}
```

------------------------- Original answer

There are a few ways to do it. One way would be to use a bitmask. I would write a function to turn the leds on/off

```c
// Each bit represents the state of one LED (0 == off, 1 == on)
byte led_bits = 0;
int ledPins[] = {3, 4, 5,};
const int num_leds = sizeof(ledPins) / sizeof(ledPins[0]);  // 3 in this example
// Need a mask to make sure we don't set too many bits
const byte led_mask = 0xFF >> 8 - num_leds;   // 00000111B in this case

void set_leds() {
    for (int i = 0; i < num_leds; i++) {
        // Turn on/off based on state of bit
        digitalWrite(ledPins[i], (1 << i) & led_bits ? HIGH : LOW);
    }
}
```

Then, on button press, set the mask:

```c
led_bits << = 1;          // Shift left (001 -> 010)
led_bits |= 1;            // Set lsb    (010 -> 011)
led_bits &= led_mask;     // Ensure max bits: (1111 -> 0111)
set_leds();
```

Then to turn the leds off with the other button press:

```c
led_bits >>= 1;          // Shift right (011 -> 001)
set_leds();
```